# Wordpress - require wp-db

Tags: php, wordpress, thread-safety

```
require_once( 'wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
```

I created a script in WordPress directory and I use only this require. Is it safe?

Comment: Is safe for what? What's your concern?

Comment: Use the $wpdb Object https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: is safe for use in other script